# win10: boots successfully from external ssd in usb adapter, but when ssd is used in laptop it freezes during booting

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

i've installed win10 on a ssd which is connected via usb adapter and i can successfully boot this instance. Now i want to replace the existing ssd in the notebook with the external one. But than booting hangs. The loading image: Rotating circles stops and nothing happens anymore.

Any ideas?

best regards

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 install on USB likely has very different drivers to a normal computer installation.

Best approach:  Install Windows 10 fresh either on a new disk or just re-write / set up your other disk.

Your internal drive expects to start from BIOS and internally point to the drive with proper drivers and setup. I am quite sure what you are trying to do will not work.

Comment: no, its a regular installation i think.

Comment: The drivers to start Windows from an external drive will be quite different to starting with internal BIOS and drive

Comment: Even if you could, you would spend more time making the disk work internally than just reinstalling Windows.

Comment: is there an easy way to transfer the installed programms to the new windows installation?

Comment: I keep copies of Apps and just reinstall them as needed. You cannot simply copy installed programs over to a new disk that I know of. Old style programs that tried to do this have disappeared.

Comment: I solved this problem realy easy with the use of 
Macrium reflect home free 
just cloned the drive to the internal ssd worked perfectly.